Instagram Post Location thru API
I'm making a request here:
https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/<ig-hashtag-id>/top_media?user_id=<ig-user-id>&fields=id,caption,media_type,media_url,permalink

example response:
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "17887284382178689",
            "caption": "Visual literature of Kalinga's interpretation of nature through geometric patterns. Propylene ink on wood.",
            "media_type": "IMAGE",
            "media_url": "https://scontent-mnl1-2.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/25008622_432606043809405_4524106124818907136_n.jpg?_nc_cat=110&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=18de74&_nc_ohc=BsfOfjgpxugQ7kNvgGvos4J&_nc_ht=scontent-mnl1-2.cdninstagram.com&edm=APCawUEEAAAA&oh=00_AYDeM3F_FCkCYs9CO2eALcn-1Zc8cXRjDszE9bUIKvWYMA&oe=66E0275E",
            "permalink": "https://www.instagram.com/p/Bc6461zHsE7/"
        },
        {
            "id": "17866280464216878",
            "caption": "\"Traversing Tabuk City to the sleepy town of Tinglayan is one of the roughest road I'v ever been to. Composed of narrow roads and limited pathways, this road is not for the faint hearted. You need to trust the driver maneuvering the vehicle and hopefully he brings you safely to your destination. .\n\nThe long hours of travel, there are no phone signals, the only thing you need to focus on is the view around you.\"  jpxdavid",
            "media_type": "IMAGE",
            "media_url": "https://scontent-mnl1-2.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/27894116_147572912599336_2290924483260710912_n.jpg?_nc_cat=109&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=18de74&_nc_ohc=XIrmLk4n-EMQ7kNvgHJqdp5&_nc_ht=scontent-mnl1-2.cdninstagram.com&edm=APCawUEEAAAA&oh=00_AYAAY49IH_uTMezzet35bt6n289oRKLOoAdNT1HijQMBJA&oe=66E0271A",
            "permalink": "https://www.instagram.com/p/BfkudLeFQiL/"
        }
   ]
}

but I want to the location of the photo back. how can I do this?
by location I mean the little string that appears above the photo in the feed
